# using mvcmailer in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I'm trying to use mvcmailer in my mvc web app. When I used it in a dummy project and continued the steps stated in the wiki, it worked fine and I was able to send an email.

But when I tried to integrate it in my web app, its giving an error at "PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "Welcome");" stating that it is unable to find _Layout.text. _Layout.text.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml exists in Usermailer folder along with Welcome.cshtml.

Usermailer code

```
public class UserMailer : MailerBase, IUserMailer     
    {
        public UserMailer():
            base()
        {
            MasterName="_Layout";
        }
public virtual MailMessage Welcome(string email, string validationUrl)
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "Welcome to GiftSocial"};

            mailMessage.To.Add(email);
            ViewBag.Validationkey = validationUrl;
            PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "Welcome");

            return mailMessage;
        } 
}
```

Controller code

UserMailer.Welcome(email: model.Email, validationUrl: validationUrl).Send();

Copied exception Details:

```
System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The layout page "_Layout.text" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/UserMailer/_Layout.text".
  Source=Mvc.Mailer
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at Mvc.Mailer.StringResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context, String mailerName)
       at Mvc.Mailer.MailerBase.EmailBody(String viewName, String masterName)
       at Mvc.Mailer.MailerBase.PopulateTextBody(MailMessage mailMessage, String viewName, String masterName)
       at Mvc.Mailer.MailerBase.PopulateBody(MailMessage mailMessage, String viewName, String masterName, Dictionary`2 linkedResources)
       at MvcGiftSocial.Mailers.UserMailer.Welcome(String email, String validationUrl) 
       at MvcGiftSocial.Controllers.AccountController.Register(RegisterViewModel viewmodel, String returnUrl) in C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GiftSocialAzureNew\MvcGiftSocial\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 86
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

I would sincerely appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong..

Thanks
Arnab

Comment: Can you please post your shared layout and your view and view model

Comment: I'm using the same _Layout and Welcome.cshtml that comes with mvcmailer, I have not yet changed anything

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory. The required views were not found.
It seems that you were trying to send text/plain mail message. Therefor MvcMailer was looking for such views.

See: https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide#wiki-send-multi-part-emails